# sudo apt update not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, updates, wine, ppa, update-manager

It is giving the following error

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease [5,931 B]                                                          
                                                
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tomtomtom/woeusb/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                         
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                     
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                           
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY xxxxxxxx
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You don't have to censor out public keys ...

Comment: For unsigned repositories you could try `sudo apt update --allow-insecure-repositories`. It will bypass the error saying the repository is unsigned.

Comment: The WineHQ pubkey error is a well-known issue.